# ELK with RabbitMQ forwarding logs using NLog fails

Tags: rabbitmq, nlog

I have the following setup: a ELK stack on CentOS server with RB with mirrored Queue. Publishers are using Nlog-HAF-Rabbitmq appender to forward logs to RabbitMQ nodes behind load balancer.
One publisher is a web application which hosted on IIS. Sometimes, it stops logging to ELK stack post-recycle which happens early in morning.

Here are my findings:

1. I logged Nlog internal logs to identify if any connection failure.
2. while recycling we have Warning on Event viewer on WAS
   A process serving application pool  exceeded time limits during shut down. The process id.
   A worker process serving application pool  failed to stop a listener channel for protocol 'http' in the allotted time.  The data field contains the error number.

IIS shutdown time limit 3 seconds (default)
IIS start up time limit 3 seconds (default)

Based information above, what could be the reason?